# Why do so many films in the 2010s leave the title to the end?

Tags: film-techniques, title-sequence

I've noticed the trend of leaving the title to the end especially in almost every single recent Marvel film, several Disney films, and some other action blockbusters. Personally I enjoy the effect of having the title of the film in the beginning, to ramp up excitement for what I'm about to watch. It's generally one of the moments I really look forward to in almost each film I watch, to see how it's executed, how it sets the tone of the film and also because it's an important element when it comes to the flow and pacing of the film.

Sometimes leaving the title to the end works, like in *The Dark Knight* - that worked REALLY well - like in films where the ending of the film culminates to the title itself, like it did with TDK, or for example *Big Hero 6*. With those I understand it since the title gets its actual meaning from the ending.

Other times, I don't really understand the reasoning behind leaving the title to the end of the film - especially if it's left to the end credits, at which point I feel it serves no purpose anymore other than it being "obligatory". Sometimes I feel that going with the trend of not introducing the title, or doing it at the very end, is a waste of dramatic effect.

What is the reason why it is so common now?

Comment: +1 As an addendum to this, I'd love to know which film did it first - as it's definitely become the popular way to do it these days. Who led the trend?

Comment: I wondered that too - I'm sure it's not a new invention by any means, but I'm certainly very curious as to why it's become so popular only so recently.

Comment: There's a bit here, as to who was first - but they're a long time before the current trend - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closing_credits#History - "West Side Story showed only the title at the beginning of the film, and Around the World in 80 Days had no opening credits at all."

Comment: @Tetsujin An extreme example of this is Apocalypse Now. Francis Ford Coppola omitted all on-screen credits, and only had the title as a graffiti in the movie.