# Why does the movie title appear at the end of the movie?

Tags: title-sequence, john-wick-chapter-4

What is the significance of the title "John Wick Chapter 4" appearing at
the end of the movie?

Comment: This is very common more recently; [this question didn't get any answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/100244/why-do-so-many-films-in-the-2010s-leave-the-title-to-the-end) but [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CloseOnTitle) discusses other examples.